# redis subscription notification

Tags: redis, notifications, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to get a notification if some one subscribe to a certain topic in redis. For example A can subscribe to B using SUBSCRIBE B command but want if B doesnot want A to subscribe to it. Is there is  a way that B gets a notification when A subscribe to it ?